# Monitor System.Reflection.Assembly dynamically loaded dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, reflection, monitor

I was unsure on how to title this question so if you think the title can be improved please feel free to edit.

So, I don't usually code in vb.net but this time as a school homework I'm required to do it.
It is about calling a set of 6 dll's with System.Reflection.Assembly. I've managed to do so using the following code:

```
For Each dll As String In loadedDLLs
            Dim newAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly =
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(dll)
            For Each dat As System.Type In newAssembly.GetExportedTypes
                Dim x As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(dat)
                Dim args() As [Object] = {}
                dat.InvokeMember("init", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, x, args)
            Next
        Next
```

In the code above, dll is the path from the dll  file, and I execute the "init" method on each dll "loaded" by the `OpenFileDialog`

What I need to do is to add it to a DataGridView, and update the gird every Timer.Tick interval with relevant system usage stadistics. Now I've found a very usefull post that in another segment of the code allows me to monitor the execution of .exe files, here is the link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Can anyone please point me to the rigth direction on monitoring the dll performance? a code snipet or a link will be awesome.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, though there might be a better way:

Create a simple exe that takes the path to a dll as a parameter.

In your monitor app call that exe as a new process (Diagnositc.Process) passing the dll path in.

From the process object you can then get various information such as memory useage.

I would also consider recording the start and end time of the proccess to calculate the time taken.

The main issue you may have is that the init method may finish before you read the memory useage so perhaps look into the peak memory useage properties.